# PHP multiple user level login page

Tags: php, authentication

I am new to PHP and I've been stuck with this, so any help is appreciated.

In my DB I have 4 user_levels:

id
name
1
admin
2
member
3
cashier
4
unregistered_user

The problem is, when ANY user logins, it redirects it to the page profile.php.
And I need for every user to have other permissions, search results etc.
How can I do this?

login.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
 <?php include 'connect.php'; ?> 
 <?php include 'functions.php'; ?> 
 <?php include 'title_bar.php'; ?> 

<h2>Login:</h2>
<form method='POST'>
  <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];

        if(empty($username) or empty($password)){
            echo "You missed something!";

        }else{
            $check_login=mysql_query("SELECT id, type FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
            if(mysql_num_rows($check_login)!=0){
                $run=mysql_fetch_array($check_login);
                $user_id=$run['id'];
                $type=$run['type'];

                if($type=='d'){
                    echo "<p>Account not activated!</p>";

                }else{
                    $_SESSION['user_id']=$user_id;
                    header("location: profile.php");
                }

            }else{
                echo "<p>Wrong information!</p>";
            }




        }
    }


    ?>
<br/>
    username: 
    <br/>
    <input type='text' name='username'><br/>
    <br/>
    pass: 
    <br/>
    <input type='password' name='password'><br />
    <br><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login'><br/>
    </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

session_start.php

```
<?php
session_start();

    function loggedin(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])&& !empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
            return true;

        }else{
            return false;

        }

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: You will need to post some code in order to get help.

Comment: Show us your code please. But as I imagine, get the record of your user from the users table, set the permisson into a $_SESSION variable, and based on their permission, redirect them to the proper page.

Comment: You just show / hide stuff users are (not) allowed to see..

Comment: @lolka_bolka You should submit that as an answer.

Comment: sorry I added code now

Answer (score 2):

Get the record of your user from the users table, set the permisson into a $_SESSION variable, and based on their permission, redirect them to the proper page.

Of course you need to change the table names, form field names, column names, auth method, etc...

**EDIT:**

Because you added your code, this is an updated version, based on your code:

```
    if ($type == 'd') {
    echo "<p>Account not activated!</p>";
} else {
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
    $_SESSION['type'] = $run['type'];
    switch ($run["type"]) {
        case 1:
            //admin
            header("Location: admin.php");
            die();
            break;
        case 2:
            //member
            header("Location: member.php");
            die();
            break;
        case 3:
            //cashier
            header("Location: cashier.php");
            die();
            break;
        case 4:
            header("Location: unregistered.php");
            die();
            //unregistered user
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer!

Comment: I pasted this and nothing happens, no redirection, it just stays on the login form

Comment: dump out the `run["type"];` is it 1 or 2 or 3 or 4?

Comment: hm? should I delete the whole ($run["type"]) part?

Comment: no. that is where you decide, what page you show to what user.

Comment: can you explain to me what should I do with run["type"]; code?
what should I add to make it work? thanks in advance!

Comment: you are using you `type` field in your database to determinate, what user has what access level? If it's `d`, that means deleted i guess. if it is `1`, then that is admin, if it is `2` that it is a member, and so on. So, you need to create the condition based on that value. This is what i did in my code.

Comment: d is for deactivated account, a is for active(activated by admin)
yes, 1, 2, 3 etc are types of members that exist in my database.
everything seems fine and I pasted your code in mine and added few pages(cashier.php, etc), but it's still not logging in, just stands still.
user_level is what I use to determine if it's admin, cashier or so.
what do you think, why doesn't it work?
you mean that I must add a statement similar to the first one here? http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: i do not know, why not logged in. you should ask it as a question, since your question was answered, how to redirect user by permission.